# cygpath:can't convert empty path - HBase 2.1.2

Tags: java, hadoop, cygwin, hbase

I am getting a weird error when configuring the HBase on cygwin.

```
cygpath: error converting "/usr/local/hbase/bin/../conf:/usr/local/jre1.8.0_191/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/..:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/avro-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-lang3-3.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/curator-client-4.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/curator-framework-4.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/curator-recipes-4.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/disruptor-3.3.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-client-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-common-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-common-2.7.7-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.7-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-minicluster-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.7-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-annotations-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-annotations-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-client-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-common-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-common-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-endpoint-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-examples-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-external-blockcache-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-http-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-it-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-it-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-mapreduce-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-mapreduce-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-metrics-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-metrics-api-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-procedure-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-protocol-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-protocol-shaded-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-replication-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-resource-bundle-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-rest-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-rsgroup-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-rsgroup-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-server-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-server-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-shaded-miscellaneous-2.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-shaded-netty-2.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-shaded-protobuf-2.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-shell-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-testing-util-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-thrift-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-zookeeper-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hbase-zookeeper-2.1.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/httpclient-4.5.3.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/httpcore-4.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-core-2.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jamon-runtime-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jcodings-1.0.18.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-client-2.25.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jettison-1.3.8.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-http-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-io-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-jmx-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-jsp-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-security-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-server-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-util-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-util-ajax-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-xml-9.3.19.v20170502.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/joni-2.1.11.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/junit-4.12.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/metrics-core-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/spymemcached-2.12.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar" - Unknown error -1
cygpath: can't convert empty path
/usr/local/hbase/bin/../bin/hbase: line 664: /usr/local/jre1.8.0_191/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I have tried searching **cygpath:can't convert empty path** with no success.

Anyone with the solution or any lead would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: How is called `cygpath` and do all path components exist ?

Comment: @matzeri Thanks for the response, I am new to this stuff can you please help to let me know what all components need to check?

Comment: Your command line should be something like `cygpath -w -p /usr/bin:/bin`. Show us the failing script line, and any environment variables used in it if you need more help.

Comment: @DougHenderson Thanks for the reply, Actually I am configuring HBase on windows so I am calling a bash script which will call other bash files, I am really struck on how to start debugging the generic error **cygpath: can't convert empty path**. What information do I need to provide to get more help, please tell me will edit my question with that info

Comment: I can reproduce this error message by entering `cygpath -w ''`. The two single quotes cause an empty argument to be passed to `cygpath`. This can happen if you use an undefined environment variable. Unix/linux/cygwin environment variable names are case sensitive, whereas windows names are not. E.g. PATH, path and Path name 3 different variables in bash, but are the same variable in cmd. You can find more info on `cygpath` by entering `cygpath --help` at the bash prompt.